# XML to CSV using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a complex xml file that I need to parse.

The main information I need is between the `LeaseFiles` tags -- each person will not have all nodes, only if they have data in them....

I'm trying to produce a csv file with headers that will make each row same number of fields, leaving value blank if it's not in the xml file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
  <xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'|'" />

<!-- define an array containing the fields we are interested in -->
<xsl:variable name="fieldArray">
<field>TotalProperties</field>
<field>TotalLeaseFiles</field>
<field>TotalTenants</field>
<field>TotalOpenAmount</field>
</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:param name="fields" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='fieldArray']/*" />  

<xsl:template match="/">

 <!-- output the header row -->
 <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
   <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
     <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:for-each>

 <!-- output newline -->
 <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="ResMan/Response/MITS-Collections/Summary"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Summary">
 <xsl:variable name="currNode" select="." />

  <!-- output the data row -->
  <!-- loop over the field names and find the value of each one in the xml -->  
 <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
   <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
   </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="$currNode/*[name() = current()]" />
 </xsl:for-each>

 <!-- output newline -->
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is XML file

```
<MITS-Collections  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Itf_MITS_Collections3.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
<Summary>
  <MITSDocVersion />
  <GenerationTimeStamp>2017-11-03T13:11:56</GenerationTimeStamp>
  <SourceOrganization>23</SourceOrganization>
  <TotalProperties>1</TotalProperties>
  <TotalLeaseFiles>11</TotalLeaseFiles>
  <TotalTenants>12</TotalTenants>
  <TotalOpenAmount>3325.00</TotalOpenAmount>
</Summary>
<PropertyFiles>
  <PropertyFile>
    <Property>
      <Identification>
        <IDValue>47-550</IDValue>
      </Identification>
      <MarketingName />
      <LegalName />
      <Address AddressType="property">
        <Description>PropertyAddress</Description>
        <Address>Lofts </Address>
        <City>Atlanta</City>
        <State>GA</State>
        <PostalCode>30324</PostalCode>
      </Address>
    </Property>
    <LeaseFiles>
      <LeaseFile>
        <Identification>
          <IDValue>t0143556</IDValue>
          <OrganizationName>Primary Tenant Code</OrganizationName>
        </Identification>
        <Identification>
          <IDValue>206</IDValue>
          <OrganizationName>Unit Code</OrganizationName>
        </Identification>
        <CollectionStatus>true</CollectionStatus>
        <CollectionStatusLastChangeDate>2017-11-  03</CollectionStatusLastChangeDate>
      <MoveInDate>2017-05-15</MoveInDate>
      <LeaseBegin>2017-05-15</LeaseBegin>
      <LeaseEnd>2018-08-14</LeaseEnd>
      <MonthlyRentAmount>1420.00</MonthlyRentAmount>
      <Tenants>
        <PersonDetails>
          <Identification>
            <IDValue>t0143556</IDValue>
          </Identification>
          <Name>
            <FirstName>Octavia</FirstName>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
          </Name>
          <Address AddressType="current">
            <Description>current</Description>
            <Address>5832 Hunt Club Run</Address>
            <City>Norcross</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30093</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Address AddressType="current">
            <Description>current</Description>
            <Address>2430 Cheshire Bridge Road</Address>
            <City>Atlanta</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30324</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Address AddressType="previous">
            <Description>previous</Description>
            <Address>5832 Hunt Club Run</Address>
            <City>Norcross</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30093</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Address AddressType="previous">
            <Description>previous</Description>
            <Address>118 Collier Rd Nw</Address>
            <City>Atlanta</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30318</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Address AddressType="other">
            <Email>octaviar@gmail.com</Email>
          </Address>
          <Phone PhoneType="cell">
            <PhoneDescription>Mobile</PhoneDescription>
            <PhoneNumber>4049999000</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </PersonDetails>
        <DateOfBirth>1996-01-01</DateOfBirth>
        <SSN>199-99-9999</SSN>
        <DriversLicense>GA 058</DriversLicense>
        <Income>
          <IncomeSource>Other</IncomeSource>
          <IncomeAmount>600.00</IncomeAmount>
          <PaymentPeriod>Other</PaymentPeriod>
        </Income>
        <Employer>
          <EmployerDetails>
            <Identification>
              <IDValue>Alor</IDValue>
            </Identification>
            <CompanyName>Alor</CompanyName>
            <Address AddressType="other">
              <Description>Office Address</Description>
              <Address>1000 place Blvd</Address>
              <City>Kennesaw</City>
              <State>GA</State>
              <PostalCode>30318</PostalCode>
            </Address>
            <Phone PhoneType="office">
              <PhoneDescription>Office</PhoneDescription>
              <PhoneNumber>770-400-0000</PhoneNumber>
            </Phone>
          </EmployerDetails>
          <Income>
            <IncomeAmount>1600</IncomeAmount>
            <PaymentPeriod>Monthly</PaymentPeriod>
          </Income>
        </Employer>
        <Contact>
          <Identification>
            <IDValue>Ronnie Smith</IDValue>
          </Identification>
          <Name>
            <FirstName>Ronnie Smith</FirstName>
            <LastName />
          </Name>
          <Address AddressType="other">
            <Description>Residents Contact Address</Description>
            <Address />
            <City />
            <State />
            <PostalCode />
          </Address>
          <Phone PhoneType="other">
            <PhoneNumber>678-999-9999</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </Contact>

        <CustomRecords>
          <Record>
            <Name>Attachment</Name>
            <Value>t0143556_Application(1).pdf</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Attachment</Name>
            <Value>t0143556_Application.pdf</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Attachment</Name>
            <Value>t0143556_Qualifying-Criteria-Cb-Lofts.pdf</Value>
          </Record>
        </CustomRecords>
      </Tenants>
      <Tenants>
        <PersonDetails>
          <Identification>
            <IDValue>r0034758</IDValue>
            <OrganizationName>Roommate</OrganizationName>
          </Identification>
          <Name>
            <FirstName>Aj</FirstName>
            <LastName>Gober</LastName>
          </Name>
          <Address AddressType="current">
            <Description>Prospect Current Address</Description>
            <Address>118 Collier Rd</Address>
            <City>Atlanta</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30318</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Address AddressType="other">
            <Email>aj@gmail.com</Email>
          </Address>
          <Phone PhoneType="cell">
            <PhoneDescription>Mobile</PhoneDescription>
            <PhoneNumber>4709999999</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </PersonDetails>
        <DateOfBirth>1996-01-01</DateOfBirth>
        <SSN>199-99-9999</SSN>
        <DriversLicense>GA 057513427</DriversLicense>
        <Guarantor>false</Guarantor>
        <Income>
          <IncomeSource />
          <IncomeAmount>0.00</IncomeAmount>
          <PaymentPeriod>Other</PaymentPeriod>
        </Income>
        <Employer>
          <EmployerDetails>
            <Identification>
              <IDValue>Alor</IDValue>
            </Identification>
            <CompanyName>Alor</CompanyName>
            <Address AddressType="other">
              <Description>Office Address</Description>
              <Address>2120 Barrett</Address>
              <City>Kennesaw</City>
              <State>GA</State>
              <PostalCode>30144</PostalCode>
            </Address>
            <Phone PhoneType="office">
              <PhoneDescription>Office</PhoneDescription>
              <PhoneNumber>470-999-9999</PhoneNumber>
            </Phone>
          </EmployerDetails>
          <Income>
            <IncomeAmount>1600</IncomeAmount>
            <PaymentPeriod>Monthly</PaymentPeriod>
          </Income>
        </Employer>
        <Contact>
          <Identification>
            <IDValue>Ruth G</IDValue>
          </Identification>
          <Name>
            <FirstName>Ruth G</FirstName>
            <LastName />
          </Name>
          <Address AddressType="current">
            <Description>Prospects Contact Address</Description>
            <Address>5832 Hunt Club Run </Address>
            <City>Norcross</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30093</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Phone PhoneType="other">
            <PhoneNumber>770-999-9999</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </Contact>

        <CustomRecords>
          <Record>
            <Name>DOB</Name>
            <Value>01/01/1996</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Relationship</Name>
            <Value>Roommate</Value>
          </Record>
        </CustomRecords>
      </Tenants>

      <Tenants>
        <PersonDetails>
          <Identification>
            <IDValue>r0034758</IDValue>
            <OrganizationName>Roommate</OrganizationName>
          </Identification>
          <Name>
            <FirstName>Aaij</FirstName>
            <LastName>Gob</LastName>
          </Name>
          <Address AddressType="current">
            <Description>Prospect Current Address</Description>
            <Address>118 Collier Rd</Address>
            <City>Atlanta</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30318</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Address AddressType="other">
            <Email>aair@gmail.com</Email>
          </Address>
          <Phone PhoneType="cell">
            <PhoneDescription>Mobile</PhoneDescription>
            <PhoneNumber>4709999999</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </PersonDetails>
        <DateOfBirth>1996-01-13</DateOfBirth>
        <SSN>199-99-9999</SSN>
        <DriversLicense>GA 0999999</DriversLicense>
        <Guarantor>false</Guarantor>
        <Employer>
          <EmployerDetails>
            <Identification>
              <IDValue>Alorica</IDValue>
            </Identification>
            <CompanyName>Alor</CompanyName>
            <Address AddressType="other">
              <Description>Office Address</Description>
              <Address>2120 Barrett</Address>
              <City>Kennesaw</City>
              <State>GA</State>
              <PostalCode>30144</PostalCode>
            </Address>
            <Phone PhoneType="office">
              <PhoneDescription>Office</PhoneDescription>
              <PhoneNumber>470-999-9999</PhoneNumber>
            </Phone>
          </EmployerDetails>
          <Income>
            <IncomeAmount>1600</IncomeAmount>
            <PaymentPeriod>Monthly</PaymentPeriod>
          </Income>
        </Employer>
        <Contact>
          <Identification>
            <IDValue>Ruth G</IDValue>
          </Identification>
          <Name>
            <FirstName>Ruth G</FirstName>
            <LastName />
          </Name>
          <Address AddressType="current">
            <Description>Prospects Contact Address</Description>
            <Address>5832 Hunt Club Run</Address>
            <City>Norcross</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30093</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Phone PhoneType="other">
            <PhoneNumber>770-999-9999</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </Contact>
        <CustomRecords>
          <Record>
            <Name>DOB</Name>
            <Value>01/01/1996</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Relationship</Name>
            <Value>Roommate</Value>
          </Record>
        </CustomRecords>
      </Tenants>
      <FileTransactions>
        <Identification>
          <IDValue>702571946</IDValue>
        </Identification>
        <TransDate>2017-04-28</TransDate>
        <TransTypeDesc>Administrative Income</TransTypeDesc>
        <TransType>Charge</TransType>
        <TransAmount>75.00</TransAmount>
        <OpenAmount>75.00</OpenAmount>
        <CustomRecords>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code</Name>
            <Value>appfee</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code Desc</Name>
            <Value>Application Fee</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Transaction Note</Name>
            <Value>Application Fee :Write Off by Charge Ctrl# 3053299</Value>
          </Record>
        </CustomRecords>
      </FileTransactions>
      <FileTransactions>
        <Identification>
          <IDValue>702571947</IDValue>
        </Identification>
        <TransDate>2017-04-28</TransDate>
        <TransTypeDesc>Administrative Income</TransTypeDesc>
        <TransType>Charge</TransType>
        <TransAmount>200.00</TransAmount>
        <OpenAmount>200.00</OpenAmount>
        <CustomRecords>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code</Name>
            <Value>admin</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code Desc</Name>
            <Value>Administration Fee</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Transaction Note</Name>
            <Value>Administration Fee :Write Off by Charge Ctrl# 2892820</Value>
          </Record>
        </CustomRecords>
      </FileTransactions>
    </LeaseFile>


    <LeaseFile>
      <Identification>
        <IDValue>t0285552</IDValue>
        <OrganizationName>Primary Tenant Code</OrganizationName>
      </Identification>
      <Identification>
        <IDValue>214</IDValue>
        <OrganizationName>Unit Code</OrganizationName>
      </Identification>
      <CollectionStatus>true</CollectionStatus>
      <CollectionStatusLastChangeDate>2017-11-03</CollectionStatusLastChangeDate>
      <LeaseBegin>2017-07-24</LeaseBegin>
      <LeaseEnd>2018-07-23</LeaseEnd>
      <MonthlyRentAmount>1181.00</MonthlyRentAmount>
      <Tenants>
        <PersonDetails>
          <Identification>
            <IDValue>t0285552</IDValue>
          </Identification>
          <Name>
            <FirstName>Ahshion</FirstName>
            <LastName>Nea</LastName>
          </Name>
          <Address AddressType="current">
            <Description>current</Description>
            <Address>1000 Bar</Address>
            <City>Atlanta</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30324</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Address AddressType="current">
            <Description>current</Description>
            <Address>2430 Cheshire Bridge Road</Address>
            <City>Atlanta</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30324</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Address AddressType="previous">
            <Description>previous</Description>
            <Address>1000 Bar</Address>
            <City>Atlanta</City>
            <State>GA</State>
            <PostalCode>30324</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <Address AddressType="other">
            <Email>ral6@gmail.com</Email>
          </Address>
          <Phone PhoneType="home">
            <PhoneDescription>Home</PhoneDescription>
            <PhoneNumber>7169999999</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </PersonDetails>
        <DateOfBirth>1996-01-01</DateOfBirth>
        <SSN>199-99-9999</SSN>
        <DriversLicense>NY 403</DriversLicense>
        <Income>
          <IncomeSource />
          <IncomeAmount>0.00</IncomeAmount>
          <PaymentPeriod>Other</PaymentPeriod>
        </Income>
        <Employer>
          <EmployerDetails>
            <Identification>
              <IDValue>Comcast</IDValue>
            </Identification>
            <CompanyName>Comcast</CompanyName>
            <Address AddressType="other">
              <Description>Office Address</Description>
              <Address>4700 N Point</Address>
              <City>Alpharetta</City>
              <State>GA</State>
              <PostalCode>30005</PostalCode>
            </Address>
            <Phone PhoneType="office">
              <PhoneDescription>Office</PhoneDescription>
              <PhoneNumber>(678) 999-9999</PhoneNumber>
            </Phone>
          </EmployerDetails>
          <Income>
            <IncomeAmount>0</IncomeAmount>
            <PaymentPeriod>Monthly</PaymentPeriod>
          </Income>
        </Employer>
        <Contact>
          <Identification>
            <IDValue>Kiron McC</IDValue>
            <OrganizationName>Friend</OrganizationName>
          </Identification>
          <Name>
            <FirstName>Kiron McC</FirstName>
            <LastName />
          </Name>
          <Address AddressType="other">
            <Description>Residents Contact Address</Description>
            <Address />
            <City />
            <State />
            <PostalCode />
          </Address>
          <Phone PhoneType="other">
            <PhoneNumber>4049999999</PhoneNumber>
          </Phone>
        </Contact>
      </Tenants>
      <FileTransactions>
        <Identification>
          <IDValue>702888725</IDValue>
        </Identification>
        <TransDate>2017-07-21</TransDate>
        <TransTypeDesc>Administrative Income</TransTypeDesc>
        <TransType>Charge</TransType>
        <TransAmount>200.00</TransAmount>
        <OpenAmount>200.00</OpenAmount>
        <CustomRecords>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code</Name>
            <Value>admin</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code Desc</Name>
            <Value>Administration Fee</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Transaction Note</Name>
            <Value>Administrative Fee (Ahshion Neasman) :Write Off by Charge Ctrl# 3211113</Value>
          </Record>
        </CustomRecords>
      </FileTransactions>
      <FileTransactions>
        <Identification>
          <IDValue>702888726</IDValue>
        </Identification>
        <TransDate>2017-07-21</TransDate>
        <TransTypeDesc>Administrative Income</TransTypeDesc>
        <TransType>Charge</TransType>
        <TransAmount>75.00</TransAmount>
        <OpenAmount>75.00</OpenAmount>
        <CustomRecords>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code</Name>
            <Value>appfee</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code Desc</Name>
            <Value>Application Fee</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Transaction Note</Name>
            <Value>Application Fee (Ahshion Neasman) :Write Off by Charge Ctrl# 3211101</Value>
          </Record>
        </CustomRecords>
      </FileTransactions>
      <FileTransactions>
        <Identification>
          <IDValue>703092265</IDValue>
        </Identification>
        <TransDate>2017-08-25</TransDate>
        <TransTypeDesc>Late / NSF Fees</TransTypeDesc>
        <TransType>Charge</TransType>
        <TransAmount>50.00</TransAmount>
        <OpenAmount>50.00</OpenAmount>
        <CustomRecords>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code</Name>
            <Value>nsf</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Charge Code Desc</Name>
            <Value>NSF Fee</Value>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <Name>Transaction Note</Name>
            <Value>Returned check charge :Write Off by Charge Ctrl# 3211110</Value>
          </Record>
        </CustomRecords>
      </FileTransactions>
    </LeaseFile>
  </LeaseFiles>
 </PropertyFile>
```

Want the resulting file to be pipe delimited and have all fields whether they have data or not....I have the schema as well so not sure if I can compare it to that and any nodes that aren't in the 'record' it populates with blank...I could also get by if the values in the delimited file were   nodeName:text value, I could then parse it from there....

Comment: What have you tried so far? A [quick SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxslt%5D+XML+to+CSV) delivers you plenty of approaches.

Comment: Each *LeaseFile* contains **multiple** tags with **the same name**,
e.g. *IDValue* (in various places), *OrganizationName*, address and phone details.
Do you want **all** such tags in the output CSV or e.g. only the first
tag with particular name? In which order?
Tag *Tenants* has **plural** form, which suggests that there can be also
**multiple** *PersonDetails* tags (each for a tenant). What about such cases?

Comment: Ideally I would like all values returned - in order they are in the XML document

Comment: You might help your cause, if you add the expected output.  Also, these nodes ResMan/Response/MITS-Collections/Summary don't exist in the XML.  So, your apply-templates is not doing anything.

Comment: Was it suppose to be  <xsl:apply-templates select="Res/Response/MITS/Summary"/> ?

Comment: Yes sorry   select="Res/Response/MITS/Summary"  but then I also want it to look down further in the tree, through LeaseFiles, etc

Comment: I want output to be header row and then data - all pipe delimited                  TotalProperties|TotalLeaseFiles|TotalTenants|TotalOpenAmount|CollectionStatus|CollectionStatusLastChangeDate|MoveInDate|MoveOutDate|NoticeToVacateDate|LeaseBegin|LeaseEnd|MonthlyRentAmount|FirstName|LastName|Address(current)|City|State|PostalCode|Country|Address(prior)|City|State|PostalCode|Country.....etc all the way down -- each <LeaseFile> record will be it's own line until it hits </LeaseFiles> and it's done

Comment: Would be simple if this was just simple standard static XML but this is dynamic XML so don't know how to end up with a csv file that has same amount of fields in each line

Comment: You say this file is 'dynamic' which suggests an infinite number of possible fields. But .csv file by very structure needs field definitions for consistent output across rows. If not, you'll need to go through the file once to get all the possible fields (empty or not), and then use those resulting fields to go through the file a second time and output the fie .csv.

Comment: Does it help at all that I have the XSD schema file? Can it be matched against that, and if doesn't find that node/element, it populates a blank field?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<xsl:output method="text" />

<!-- define an array containing the fields we are interested in -->
<xsl:variable name="fieldArray">
  <field>TotalProperties</field>
  <field>TotalLeaseFiles</field>
  <field>TotalTenants</field>
  <field>TotalOpenAmount</field>
  <field>CollectionStatus</field>
  <field>MoveInDate</field>
  <field>MoveOutDate</field>
  <field>TenantFirstName</field>
  <field>TenantL‌​astName</field>
  <field>TenantCity</field>
  <field>ContactFirstName</field>
  <field>ContactL‌​astName</field>
  <!-- Add the rest of the fields. -->
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'|'" />

<xsl:variable name="fields" select="msxml:node-set($fieldArray)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <!-- output the header row -->
  <xsl:for-each select="$fields/field">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>

  <!-- Store the summary values in a variable. -->
  <xsl:variable name="summary">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Summary//TotalProperties" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'TotalProperties'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Summary//TotalLeaseFiles" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'TotalLeaseFiles'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Summary//TotalTenants" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'TotalTenants'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Summary//TotalOpenAmount" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'TotalOpenAmount'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <!-- Add any more values from the summary field here. -->
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="summaryList" select="msxml:node-set($summary)"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select=".//LeaseFile">
    <xsl:with-param name="summaryList" select="$summaryList"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LeaseFile">
  <xsl:param name="summaryList"/>

  <!-- output newline -->
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

  <!-- Store the lease file values in a variable. -->
  <xsl:variable name="leaseFileValues">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//MoveInDate" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'MoveInDate'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//MoveOutDate" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'MoveOutDate'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//CollectionStatus" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'CollectionStatus'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Tenants/PersonDetails/Name/FirstName" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'TenantFirstName'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Tenants/PersonDetails/Address/City" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'TenantCity'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Tenants/PersonDetails/Name/LastName" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'TenantL‌​astName'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Tenants/Contact/Name/FirstName" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'ContactFirstName'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Tenants/Contact/Name/LastName" mode="values">
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'ContactL‌​astName'"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <!-- Add the rest of the fields. -->
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="leaseFileValuesList" select="msxml:node-set($leaseFileValues)"/>

  <!-- Loop through the field. -->
  <xsl:for-each select="$fields/field">
    <xsl:variable name="currentField" select="."/>

    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:for-each select="$summaryList/element[name=$currentField and value!='' and not(value = preceding-sibling::element[name=$currentField][1]/value)]/value">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'^'"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="$leaseFileValuesList/element[name=$currentField and value!='' and not(value = preceding-sibling::element[name=$currentField][1]/value)]/value">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'^'"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="values">
  <xsl:param name="name"/>
  <element>
    <name>
      <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    </name>
    <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </value>
  </element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: When running  xsltproc with the above, I get    xmlXpathCompOpEval: function node-set not found      Xpath error : Unregistered function    runtime error: file stacksample.xsl line 20 element variable   Evaluating global variable   being computed ... failed

Comment: Add this to your stylesheet tag:  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"    If that does not work, what XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I have it in there just as you have in your code.....I'm running CentOS 5.10 and xsltproc -V produces:   Using libxml 20626, libxslt 10117 and libexslt 813
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20626, libxslt 10117 and libexslt 813
libxslt 10117 was compiled against libxml 20626
libexslt 813 was compiled against libxml 20626

Comment: In XSLT version 1.0, whenever you create a RTF (result tree fragment) you will have to convert it to a node-set.

Comment: Here are some processor namespaces that you can try:                                                      
Processor Function name Namespace
EXSLT aware processors (Saxon, xsltproc, Xalan-J, jd.xslt, 4XSLT) node-set() http://exslt.org/common
MSXML node-set() urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt
Xalan-C nodeset() http://xml.apache.org/xalan
Sablotron Can operate on result tree fragments directly.

Comment: You may not even need node sets.  So, you can rename the variables used in the node-set functions to the name of the corresponding node-set variable.  And, then remove the node-set variable altogether.  So, for example, summary becomes summaryList.  And, summary List is deleted.

Comment: Thanks - I'll see what I can figure out - your last comments are sadly out of my scope of understanding but I appreciate you taking the time to reply with more information and your example code etc...I do appreciate it

Comment: I think I answered you original question.  So, I would appreciate you checking the up arrow for the answer.  You can uncheck it later, if you find out the answer is wrong.  Good luck to you.

Comment: I did - but it showed since I have less than 15 posts that votes are recorded but don't change what the public sees....thanks again

Comment: No Prolem.  Good luck~

Comment: Bluewood  was able to get it to work by changing urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt  to   http://exslt.org/common....

Comment: Things to do now are how do I get fields that have attributes? i.e. AddressType, PhoneType and how to get All FileTransactions if they have more than one?  making progress thanks!

Comment: I changed the LeaseFile template to display multiple values for a field.  I am delimiting them with a '^'.  You also need to go up to the field array and added the rest of the fields.  In this solution you have some ambiguity in some of the fields.  For example, you have tenants city and employer city....  One way to solve this is to change the tag names.  So, <City> would become <TenantsCity> for tenants and <EmployerCity> for employer.  Otherwise, you will need to figure out how to handle it.

Comment: Yeah wish they had their XML with more unique names but it's what I have to work with.....your new example spits out  Administrative Income^Administrative Income|Charge^Charge|75.00^200.00  is that the expected result?  Also plays some havoc when I add FirstName and LastName in the fields array, because there are multiple instances of those too...ugh...thanks again!!

Comment: Is there a way to add the node name then the value?  i.e.  Tenants FirstName: <value>    Contact FirstName: <value> ?

Comment: See new code edit.  Just finish the pattern I started and you should have something close to what you want.  Notice the name is sometimes different that the element being selected in the apply-templates.

Comment: So do I need to rename the xml elements to TenantFirstName, ContactFirstName? etc     I didn't see your comments in your code, but when I initially tried this, I get an error  parser error: premature end of data in tag stylesheet line 1....not sure if that's because I haven't finished all the rest of the fields?

Comment: No, leave the XML alone.   Are you getting the error you mention when you just run the code I provided?   Of course, you have to change the URL again.

Comment: Yes I'm getting it when just trying to run the code....I have changed the URL as well.....maybe when I copied/pasted it something went wrong...I'll try it again in just a few

Comment: Make sure the </xsl:stylesheet> tag is in your code.  It was not showing up in my edit.  You can see it now.

Comment: Yeah I caught that - no more errors....going to add more fields and see what I get...currently it's showing city together like 3 times  Atlanta^Atlanta^Atlanta  but I'll continue to fiddle with it - thanks again

Comment: If you really want to select distinct you can change the last two for loops in the LeaseFile template as follows.                                       <xsl:for-each select="$summaryList/element[name=$currentField and not(value = preceding-sibling::element[name=$currentField][1]/value)]/value">
 
    <xsl:for-each select="$leaseFileValuesList/element[name=$currentField and not(value = preceding-sibling::element[name=$currentField][1]/value)]/value">

Comment: For some reason, on just the very first one, it's showing the Tenant name as  Octavia^Aaijiah^Aaijiah  - but all the others shows the Tenant names correctly.....?

Comment: Post the xml you are using.

Comment: Also, consider the possibility that are three tenants.  Use the new code I post to select distinct.  but, I'm not sure you really want that.

Comment: posted xml I'm using - part of it anyways - I took some LeaseFile out cuz file was too large to upload......if there are 3 tenants under one LeaseFile that means they all signed the lease and I would want all the names

Comment: In the original XML, you only had one Tenants element within the LeaseFile element. But, in the new XML, you have several Tenants elements in a LeaseFile element. This is the cause of the issue you mentioned. So, the code as originally written works against the original XML. So, I've done my job for you. At this point, if the new XML is the target XML, I've given you the techniques needed to solve this. You have to understand and apply them. If you want, I will delete my answer, so someone else may help you.  Good luck.

Comment: I sincerely apologize - I originally posted a similar XML file but I thought it was the correct one....that's my bad....I truly appreciate your help on this - sorry for the misunderstanding....I noticed this when you asked me to post the XML file I was using - again, my sincere apologies....thanks again

Comment: The original XML I posted was more of a test file I had been given - and when I got a live file I didn't notice originally that there were more Tenants elements inside a LeaseFile....so I got thrown a curve as well....sorry again and thank you for your efforts, they truly helped

Comment: No worries.  I'm glad I helped. Cheers!

Comment: Wish you wouldn't have removed your answer though but I understand - once I get more posts on here I def wanted to up vote you! thanks again  this has become a big PITA lol  I may have to change how I parse this file and maybe use Python

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  My answer is still there.  If you want to remove it, I will.  That may prompt someone else to help you.

Comment: Oh no - my bad - you had said you were going to remove it....I didn't scroll up to see if you had......I'd prefer you leave it there....it may help someone else later and plus I'll know it's there if I screw anything up....thanks again!

Comment: I tried putting a xsl:for-each to get all Tenants but haven't gotten it to work..but still working on it...